# Render and Compile String using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There is a requirement where all html elements are defined in a JSON file and used in the template.

There is a function - "markComplete" which needs to be triggered on change of a checkbox.

**Code Template:**

```
<template>
<span v-html="htmlContent"></span>
</template>

<script>
 data(){
        return{
        htmlContent: "<input type='checkbox' v-on:change='markComplete'>"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Above code won't work as `onChange` event won't be mounted, and I get **`Uncaught ReferenceError: markComplete is not defined`**

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: The json file is just a string, cannot contain methods. `makeComplete` would have to be defined somewhere in the Vue app - where is it?

Comment: @RichardMatsen That is present in methods, i just didn't mention it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to compile the string as Vue Templates using v-html.

> Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates

Read about v-html in [Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html).

As solution you can read [this article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/v-runtime-template/)

> You don't want to use a library? Checkout the code below:

**First create a js file (preferably `RenderString.js`):**

```
import Vue from "vue"

Vue.component("RenderString", {
  props: {
    string: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    const render = {
      template: "<div>" + this.string + "</div>",
      methods: {
        markComplete() {
          console.log('the method called')
        }
      }
    }
    return h(render)
  }
})
```

**Then in your parent component:**

```
<template>
  <div><RenderString :string="htmlContent" /></div>
</template>

<script>
import RenderString from "./components/RenderString"

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    htmlContent: "<input type='checkbox' v-on:change='markComplete'>"
  })
}
</script>
```

Note: I didn't run the code above but I created a similar working [CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zw17jrlvqp)

Comment: thanks for the edit. This works fine but function defined in parent component should be called. I tried to emit event on change - this.$emit('ParentFunction');

On doing this, there is neither error nor warning. Where am I going wrong?
CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/k34x9jk02r

Comment: Glad to read that it helped. Though I changed the sandbox using $emit. If you want you can take a look -> https://codesandbox.io/s/x2vry0m8mp