# Is possible to put html element inside variable in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have some issue with Vue.js. In my Component i got other component by ref and i need change some of his properties from pure text to inputs with predefined text.

My method looks like this:

```
 addCustomItem(event){      
                let grid = this.$refs.customItemGrid.items;
                //Grid alredy have 2 items with amount property

                //this is what i need to do... (Now amount is just value (f.e. 42)
                grid[0].amount = <b-form-select>  grid[0].amount <b-form-select>;
                //but i can't pass tag to variable like this.
            }
```

//**Množství** means amount in my lang.
[Final Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc4GE.png)

Comment: Are you using a library for your grid? Most libraries provide some sort of scoped slot templating for this kind of thing.

Comment: Would that be helpful -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54618473/6385184

Comment: Grid is in Custom component and it use b-table in his template something like this:                                                                                                                       
<b-table
                striped hover :busy="isBusy" :fields="fields" :items="items" :show- 
                empty="true"
                :empty-text="'Nebyly nalezeny žádné záznamy'"                                    
></btable> .  So i am not sure if is it possible to change just some fields to inputs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, because it is not html code, but component.
You can pass html via in v-html directive, but it won't work for components.

Possible solution.

In template:

`<b-form-select v-if="grid[0]">{{grid[0]}}<b-form-select>`

in script:

```
data: {
  return {
    grid: []
  }
},
methods: {
  addCustomItem (event) {      
    this.grid = this.$refs.customItemGrid.items;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response but there is problem becouse in Grid compoment template is used <b-table> so i have no idea how to use v-if on just some cols from <b-table>

Comment: Check this out: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#formatter-callback